# Conversion of generic collections

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

Why I can do the following conversion:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>();
IEnumerable<Object> iStrings = strings as IEnumerable<Object>;
List<Object> oStrings = iStrings.ToList();
```

But I can't do it straight:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>();
List<Object> oStrings = strings as List<Object>;
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. `.ToList()` calls a method. It does not cast or convert other than perhaps in the plain English meaning of the word, which doesn't make sense to me in the rest of your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @hvd It *does* convert.  It doesn't cast.

Comment: @Servy In the plain English meaning of the word, perhaps. In the C# meaning of the word, it doesn't. And the question suggests to me (possibly incorrectly) the C# meaning of the word. I already covered that in my comment.

Comment: @hvd No.  This is converting the object, in the C# meaning of the word.  Creating a new object that holds content that is conceptually the same as another is what it means to "convert" an object into another type in C#, which is exactly what `ToList` is doing.

Comment: @Servy In the C# language specification, as far as I have ever seen, "convert" just means implicit type conversions and explicit ones, the explicit ones being casts. I don't know what other possible C# meaning you're thinking of.

Comment: @hvd Those are two ways you can convert objects, yes.  The fact that you can write an operator to convert an object to another type doesn't mean you can't also write a method to convert an object to another type, or that such a method isn't "converting" the object, because it is.

Comment: @Servy Again, in the ordinary English meaning of the word, I am not disputing that at all, but where does the C# language specification *ever* use "convert" in that sense? Or what other reference can you give as a better "C# meaning"? All I'm getting from you as an argument so far is "nu-uh!", which isn't particularly productive.

Comment: @hvd If the OP had said that `ToList` was performing a user defined implicit conversion, then yes, that would be the wrong term.  Saying that it's converting the object is entirely correct.  Saying that it doesn't make sense to use the word in this context just isn't true.  It'd be like saying that if I claimed that I iterated a list using a `foreach` that it wouldn't be a correct usage of the word "iterate" because it's not in the C# language specs.  A term doesn't need to be defined in the language specs to make sense when using it while asking a question about some code.

Comment: @Servy Now you're responding to an argument I never made. I don't think it's wrong to use the word in the plain English meaning, or any other intelligible meaning, when referring to C# code. I never claimed it would be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable<T>` is [*covariant*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), meaning it can be applied to derived types of `T`.  If you're at the zoo *looking at* an exhibit with several lions, it's perfectly reasonable to also say you're looking at several *animals*.

`List<T>` is *not* covariant, meaning it can not be applied to derived types.  It
's *not* appropriate to call a lion exhibit a collection of *animal* when you consider *adding* items.  You can't add a gazelle to a lion exhibit or bad things will happen.

When you call `ToList<object>` on an `IEnumerable<object>`, you create a *new collection* with the references *typed to object*.  You can safely add new objects to that list. You can't just "cast" a `List<string>` to a `List<object>` because that would imply that you could add other objects besides strings, which is not the case because it is a *list of `string`s*.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But in order to allow casting of my custom generic classes ( like Custom<CustomType1> ct1 = new Custom<CustomType1>(); Custom<CustomType2> ct2 = (Custom<CustomType2>)ct1 ) i should overload conversion operators in my Custom<T> class?